# XCode 4 bug : Multiple build command for output file

Tags: xcode4.2

I tryed desperately to use the "Add localisation" on the right menu of xCode 4.2. I wanted to localise an image... This command never worked and had a very strange behavor.

So i made it manually (creating with finder the .lproj folders).

Then I deleted my non-localised image (outside the .lproj folders) in my XCode project explorer.
Now I have some warnings and error : XCode try to access the deleted image (Multiple build command for output file). Of course, I tried to search for the image, but search filters return nothing at all.

So I need to clean my project file, but I don't know how to and I'm afraid of deterioring my project...

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: If you were using Time Machine, you could restore the project to where you were at an hour ago.  But I bet you don't have a Time Machine volume on your machine, do you?

Comment: Yeah... just as I expected. Please add a Time Machine volume and it'll save you headaches down the road.  Anyways, you should edit your question to add a screenshot of your project window and the error you're seeing. Oh, and "deleting" a file within Xcode 4 (where you have an alert to choose between "remove reference" or "delete") really *does* delete the file. This is a bad change of behavior from Xcode 3 (which used to move the file to the trash) and you should file a bug with Apple, like other developers have surely done.

Comment: Arg ! Not enough reputation to add an image !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem... or i should say Xcode probem.

I'm pretty sure it was a bug of this marvelous 4.2 version.
If you have the same problem, you should directly edit your xcode project file :

- **First, duplicate your project folder**, just in case...
- open your "Project.xcodeproj" (right click, then third option ("afficher le contenu du paquet" in french)),
- edit with a text editor (as smultron for example) the project.pbxproj file
- research for the problematic files
- delete the blocks of code where they are.
- Save.
- Lauch your project, then **clean it** (cmd shift K)

No problem anymore !